# Excel: Generating something X times based on variable

Tags: excel, ms-office

I am trying to generate a set of random numbers. I will be using the RANDBETWEEN(x,y).

My problem is now, let's say I have a calculated sum at a cell. Is there any way for the random number to be generated n amount of times, based on that number?

For example if a cell C4 = 30, then I want to generate 30 random numbers, and put them in the cells for the calculation. I am having a hard time finding out where to look for the answer to this ..

Thank you for your time

EDIT: That would in other words also mean that if the number n changes, so would the number of generated random numbers.

EDIT2:
Why am I getting this error when entering the same as you?

[image]

Comment: Put this in the cell where you want the random numbers to start, and then copy down as much as necessary: `=IF(ROW(A1)>$C$4,"",RANDBETWEEN(x,y))`

Comment: @tigeravatar Do you have any documentation for this solution? It's not working for me. What is ROW(A1)?

Comment: ROW(A1) gets the row number of cell A1, which is `1`.  As you copy the formula down, the reference cell will change to ROW(A2) and then ROW(A3), etc.  As for why the formula didn't work for you, did you actually change `x` and `y` to your desired minimum and maximum numbers?

Comment: Please look at the edit

Comment: It looks like due to your regional settings, the formula argument separator is actually a semicolon `;` instead of a comma `,`.  Try entering the formula like this instead: `=IF(ROW(A1)>$C$4;"";RANDBETWEEN(10;99))`

Comment: You were right. So regional settings, meaning the actual editing language could have different codes? I actually had the Swedish version, but changed to English because the function names were in Swedish, which is just stupid. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your number in **C4**, in **D1** enter:

```
=IF(ROW()>$C$4,"",RANDBETWEEN(10,99))
```

and copy downward.

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Your Regional Settings may require this formula instead:

```
=IF(ROW()>$C$4;"";RANDBETWEEN(10,99))
```

Comment: I am doing the same as you, but get an error message. Please look at my edit on the original post to see the picture.

Comment: @diaco  See my **EDIT#1**